# Volume is reset after suspend or hibernate in KDE Plasma

Tags: linux, audio, hibernate, kde, suspend

OS: Manjaro (updated on Aug 30,2020)
Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.19.4 (Originally Gnome)
Sound server: PulseAudio 13.0

Hello! I met a strange problem and didn't find any solutions.

The volume of my laptop won't be remembered in some cases. It is always reset to 46% after waking up from suspending or hibernating. In the contrast, it won't be reset if I reboot the OS.

BTW, the problem only occurs in KDE Plasma. I was using Gnome before but didn't notice the problem.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

---

EDIT:

Here is the log from `pulseaudio -vvvv`.
https://pastebin.com/sKbGJHva

At line 1827, I muted the volume.
Between line 1830 and 1831, I suspended my laptop and then resumed it.